# DApp examples containing complete source code

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript, react

can someone provide me some high quality ethereum dapp codebase examples? This should comprise of not only the smart contract codebase but also the app codebase , complete with the front end UI (preferably React), middle end controller codes using Javascript and possibly drizze (or similar substitutes), and even possible server side scripts to derive off-chain data from APIs or databases, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the dApps are fully open source, due to their nature of transparent development on Github. dApps have links to respective Github organisations on their homepages.

You can find dApps for example here:

https://walletconnect.org/apps

And here:

https://defipulse.com/

If you want to weed out a particular example check e.g. Uniswap and Aave:

https://github.com/uniswap

https://github.com/aave/